# Applying a new code template to existing java file

Tags: java, eclipse

We have lot of java files which were developed using a `code formatter` ,`code style` (has copyright info) templates. Now we decided to update the formatter and style  template. Is it possible to update all the java files based on the new `code formatter` and `code style` templates?

It is a tedious process to manually go and edit all copy right statements in the java files. So if we could do it quickly, it will be very helpful for us.

We are using `eclipse v3.4` for our development.

Comment: try eclipse inbuilt formatters or DIY by writing a small java class which iterates all files recursively and does expected modification using file IO.

Comment: This looks like a very good approach which we can try..

Comment: @Apps Did you found any firm solution on "Applying copyrights to existing code without writing it manually" Problem?

Comment: @Pankaj - Nothing so far Pankaj :(

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Eclipse 3.4 is quite old, so I'm not 100% sure this feature is available...

Right-click on the project or package you want to format, and select *Source* > *Format*.

That will only apply the format settings selected in Preferences/Java/ Code Style/Formatter. It will not add or alter code or comments. You choose a template when you create a new class/file.

Comment: We can use a newer version of eclipse, not a problem. will try this definitely.Thanks

Answer (score 0):

yes, manually this works with Ctrl-Shift-f, which autoformats the current code / class, with the formatting rules.

For full automatic reformatting via batch you need further answers. But beware sometimes the rukles can destroy the readability of some special classes.
I would prefer manually go throug all classes, and apply Ctrl-Shift-f.
During this you might see, than some formatting rules should be adapted.